# Por qué yajra no me ordena la consulta hecha en query builder laravel?

Tags: laravel, datatables, querybuilder

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
  $denuncias = DB::table('denuncias')
                 ->join('imputados','denuncias.imputado_id','=','imputados.idImputado')
                 ->select('denuncias.idDenuncia as idDenuncia',
                           DB::raw('CONCAT(imputados.nombre," ", imputados.apPaterno," ",imputados.apMaterno) as imputado'),
                           'denuncias.fechaRegistro',
                ->orderBy('denuncias.fechaRegistro','DESC')
                ->get();
```

Y esta consulta lo ordeno por fecha de registro la cual el campo es del tipo  datetime, ahora se lo paso al Yajra datables:

```
return Datatables::of($denuncias)->make(true);
```

y este registro se visualiza en mi vista blade, el único problema es que no ordena por fecha, como si omitiera el orderby, ahora cuando hago la consulta con postman me devuelve la consulta ordenada, entonces el problema es en el yajra. La única solución que encontré fue que desde el js lo ordene usando este comando:

```
"order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
```

Alguien sabe porque no lo ordena desde el servidor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba desactivando el order del datatables.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono

Comment: E igual funciona con "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo de esta manera:

```
$denuncias = DB::table('denuncias')
             ->join('imputados','denuncias.imputado_id','=','imputados.idImputado')
             ->select('denuncias.idDenuncia as idDenuncia',
                       DB::raw('CONCAT(imputados.nombre," ", imputados.apPaterno," ",imputados.apMaterno) as imputado'),
                       'denuncias.fechaRegistro')
            ->get();
```

Y le agregamos :

```
$denuncias = json_decode($denuncias, true);
    usort($denuncias, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['fechaRegistro'] <=> $b['fechaRegistro'];
    });
    return response()->json($denuncias);
```

Comment: Si con el return denuncias  de mi consulta al verlo enjson me aparece que esta ordenado, el problema es cuando lo paso al Datatables::of($denuncias) como si lo volviera desordenar